# Using a variable from another function

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I have a variable named Total, and it stores a character of 0, however my code is a game where the total can change from each question.
I want to be able to have the users total carry through my game, so it wont reset to 0 every time I repeat my code.

I've tried defining my variable total in another function however it needs to be defined in the one that my main chunk of code is going to be in.

```
 def FileFunction():
    Total=0 

................. LATER ON IN CODE
elif PlayAgain=="YES" or PlayAgain=="yes" or PlayAgain=="Yes":
                Play=False
                FileFunction()
```

I want it so when the total is printed at the end, as the actual total, because every time when the user gets it right, because it always reset to 0 instead of carrying the total value through every time the user gets it right and decides to play again

Comment: As you can see it resets the total value back to 0 every time the user decides to play again after getting it right, as is calls the function from the top resetting my value of Total.

Comment: You can and should not use a local variable from an other function. They exist only while the function is running. In your code you are missing two of the most important factors in defining and using functions: arguments (aka. parameters) and the return value. This is the way functions exchange data. Arguments are the input and return values the output of functions. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp for an intro!

Answer (score -1):

you need to use `global` in this case

```
Total = 2
def FileFunction():
    global Total
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: It worked, thank you I am a new coder so I didn't know about this!

Comment: Every time a global variable is used in Python a kitten dies. Please think of the kittens!